# Quintus to Android

Tags: html, phonegap-build, cocoonjs

I have tried to Google and read the Quintus wiki but no solution. Why does quintus platformer need server to run? Because this I can't use phonegap nor cocoonjs to convert my project to android game. Is there a better HTML5 2d game engine that I can use without server? Or what can I do to get quintus run as android application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I finally managed to get the game running with little bit of help, so I am answering here for myself. To get the game running on Android phone you need to quote some code.

Try commenting out this code from your `quintus.js` file and try again. I was facing a similar issue, commenting out this code resolved it:

```
if(document.location.origin === "file://" || document.location.origin === "null") {
  if(!Q.fileURLAlert) {
    Q.fileURLAlert = true;
    alert("Quintus Error: Loading assets is not supported from file:// urls - please run from a local web-server and try again");
  }
  return errorCallback();
```

Then compile it with *CocoonJS Webview+* and install `debug.apk` to get the game running.